# Add dependency for main and library project

Tags: android, build, gradle

I have a project which depends on a Android Library project in Android studio.
Now I want to use an external library in both, the library project as well as the main project.

I guess adding the library in the library project as dependency is enough right?
So I added

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
}
```

to my Library Module. But Gradle isn't able to find the library:

```
failed to find com.squareup:otto:1.3.5
```

After research I found out that i need to tell gradle where to find it using:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

But I do not know where to put this code.
Here are my Build.configs:

**Root Build.config:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()  
    }
}
```

**Main Project build.config:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {...}
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':bTLibrary')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile files('libs/commons-net-3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/dnsjava-2.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/GraphView-3.1.3.jar')
}
```

**Library Module build.config:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {...}

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'  //ERROR: GRADLE CANNOT FIND THIS LIBRARY
}
```

I have tried to put the repositories element in various places. Also in the root build.config but the error still exist. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself.
Looking at the output of the build, I found out that it was a proxy authentication problem.
Following [this](http://www.laurivan.com/gradle-and-proxy-authentication-in-android-studio/) guide solved the problem.